# Which method is better to check if a dataframe is empty ? `df.limit(1).count == 0` or `df.isEmpty`?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For the below 2 approaches to check if a dataframe is empty:

1. `df.isEmpty`
2. `df.limit(1).count == 0`

I see `df.isEmpty` has the following implementation:

```
  def isEmpty: Boolean = withAction("isEmpty", limit(1).groupBy().count().queryExecution) { plan =>
    plan.executeCollect().head.getLong(0) == 0
  }
```

Looks like it does more than directly counting.

What's the idea behind that `groupBy`? Is it just to get a dataframe?

Why is the `queryExecution` plan used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this post, I see three different questions.

### Performances

If you check carefully the source code, you can see [`df.count`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2807) does the same `groupBy` to get a [RelationalGroupedDateset](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.scala)

So, if we compare both implementations :

```
def isEmpty: Boolean = withAction("isEmpty", limit(1).groupBy().count().queryExecution) { 
  plan => plan.executeCollect().head.getLong(0) == 0
}

def count(): Long = withAction("count", groupBy().count().queryExecution) { plan =>
  plan.executeCollect().head.getLong(0)
}
```

`df.isEmpty` and `df.limit(1).count() == 0` are acting exactly the same behind the scenes.

However, I would go for `df.isEmpty` for the clarity of the name.

### Why is the `queryExecution` plan used ?

The query Execution plan is an attribute which is needed to have the global execution plan.

Each time a transformation is done, the `queryExecution` will be upgraded with this transformation.

Each time an action is done, the `queryExecution` is retrieved, and the Catalyst plan optimises it.

### What's the idea behind that `groupBy` ?

The [`count`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.scala#L237) method creates a [`RelationalGroupedDataset`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.scala) with a single group. This group is then populate with `Literal(1)` and then reduce by key (it contains no key, so it reduces every columns) concurrently to get a `DataFrame` with a single column called "count" with only one row containing the count. (This is why in the `df.count` implementation we can see a `.head.getLong(0)`

This implementation allows you to reduce concurrently in every partitions instead of creating an iterator to count.

Comment: Interesting answer and interesting handle name.

Comment: @thebluephantom Thanks :)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I still didn't get why we have queryExecution when I can write the same function simply as `def isEmpty: Boolean = limit(1).groupBy().count() == 0`. All SQL queries should be planned and optimized by the catalyst, right?!

Comment: @apnith Yes, by not returning the `query Execution` and collect it. You might miss the push down predicates of `limit1` as being the first optimization. Does that make sense ? (I edited the answer !) I do think the question about the purpose of the queryExecution might deserve a new question :)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken It makes some sense for the first optimization. But, why not do a `count` without the `groupBy`? Does that help optimize something under the hood?  `limit1` I believe should have brought the data to one executor after compute, then why that `groupBy`

Comment: @apnith I added some explanations, I hope it is clearer

Comment: @apnith Does that answer your question ? :)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I really liked the explanation on the idea behind groupBy. Though I am left with some questions on why the `queryExecution` part(will add it to a new question), this gives a good picture of "why" part of things.  Thanks! :)

Comment: @apnith I tried to add some new explanations, do not hesitate to ping me for the new question ! I am glad to help :)